# PHP-API, post to wall posts as user and not as site when link is added

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to post to a wall of a site from my php-application. It works fine, I can add a post as a site (means the post appears as being from the site on the wall).
When I add a link to the post the post gets posted in my name (being administrator of the site), but of course I'd like to have that it appears still in the name of the site.

I'm just using the normal api-call. Is this some kind of strange restriction? I remember that it worked some time ago. Any idea? Thanks.

```
$facebook->api("/mysite/feed", "post", array(
            message => $data['text'],
            name => $data['title'],
            page_id => "mysite",
            access_token => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
            link => "http://www.my_site.ch/news.php?news=" . $ret,
            caption => $data['title']
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting on a facebook page, use the `page access token` instead of the `user's access token` to post on behalf of the page; instead of user.

Read more about Page Access Token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#overview).